# Next JS Mock API endpoints send params in req.body for POST

Tags: typescript, jestjs, next.js

I have Next JS API tests running via jest using a testClient that I created:

```
import { createServer } from 'http';

import type { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import type { __ApiPreviewProps } from 'next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils';
import { apiResolver } from 'next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils';
import request from 'supertest';

export default (handler: NextApiHandler, query: Record<string, unknown> | undefined): request.SuperTest<request.Test> =>
  request(
    createServer(async (req, res) => {
      return apiResolver(req, res, query, handler, {} as __ApiPreviewProps, false);
    }),
  );
```

In my test files, I do:

```
import myEndpoint from '../myEndpoint';

describe('test endpoint', () => {
  test('verify log event endpoint fails on get request', async () => {
    expect.assertions(2);
    const client = testClient(myEndpoint, {param: 'testValue'}, false);
    const response = await client.post(‘/‘);
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    expect(response.body.success).toBe(false);
  });
```

In `myEndpoint`

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
   if (req.method !== 'POST') {
     res.json({ success: false });
     return;
   }

   // use req.body.param
```

The issue is my params are being sent in the req.query, not in the req.body - this works when I am testing GET requests, but when I make a post request to the endpoint, the parameters are set on the body, not in the query.

The `apiResolver` only has a query parameter, nothing to override the body.  How can I test my post endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to override to pass the parameters in the request body (and added a parameter to control that functionality) like this:

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, createServer } from 'http';

import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { __ApiPreviewProps, apiResolver } from 'next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils';
import request from 'supertest';

export default (
  handler: NextApiHandler,
  query: Record<string, unknown> | undefined,
  isPost: boolean,
): request.SuperTest<request.Test> =>
  request(
    createServer(async (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
      return apiResolver(
        req,
        res,
        isPost ? null : query,
        async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
          if (isPost) {
            req.body = query;
          }
          handler(req, res);
        },
        {} as __ApiPreviewProps,
        false,
      );
    }),
  );
```